# Comando Linq para trazer uma consulta decimal C#

Tags: c#, sql, query, linq

Estou com dificuldade para entender como trazer uma consulta do `textbox` de uma coluna onde o campo é decimal?

```
if (txtNomePesquisar.Text.Equals(""))
{
    MessageBox.Show("O que você procura? ");
}
else 
{       
    var clientes = cc
          .TB_CLIENTEs.Where(c => c.NOM_CLIENTE.Contains(txtNomePesquisar.Text)).ToList();
    dgvCliente.DataSource = clientes;
}

if (txtTelPesquisar.Text.Equals(""))
{

/// a mensagem é  'decimal' does contain a definition for (Contains) and...
/// e fala de IQueryable mais não sei utilizar ainda
/// 
    var clientes = cc.TB_CLIENTEs
          .Where(c => c.TEL_CLIENTE.Contains(txtTelPesquisa.Text)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: qual campo é decimal?

Comment: var clientes = cc.TB_CLIENTEs
          .Where(c => c.TEL_CLIENTE.Contains(txtTelPesquisa.Text)).ToList();

Comment: esse é o campo decimal o TEL_CLIENTE

Comment: Então eu fiz uma resposta, ve se isso é o que precisa?

Comment: Obrigado, estou tetando pois quando faço a procura com o esse codigo ele nao traz valor  mais se digito o numero 1 ele traz o registro que tem somente o numero 1 os que tem mais de um numero por exemplo : 44334, ele não traz resultados ai estou verificando o que pode ser.

Comment: O que você precisa?

Comment: o que estou com dificuldade é tenho 2 campos de pesquisa quando clica no botão pesquisar ele pode trazer a lista pelo NOME ou pelo TELEFONE no SQL sei fazer mais no C# não estou conseguindo o jeito que conseguir trazer o NOME foi como o código acima está  e separei o de TELEFONE porque não estava conseguindo colocar junto. O Que preciso é trazer a lista  tanto com o TELEFONE ou NOME quando clicado no botão PESQUISAR... estou quase alterado o tipo de dado do campo telefone para varchar se não conseguir.

Comment: Telefone é bom ser em varchar amigo... se colocou decimal na minha opinião tem um erro futuro.

Comment: Entendi acho que vou fazer isso mesmo já que está tão complicado. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro tem que verificar se realmente o valor é um `decimal`, precisa pegar o valor da caixa de texto e transformar para o `decimal`, exemplo:

```
decimal numero = 0;
if (decimal.TryParse(txtTelPesquisa.Text, out numero))
{
    var clientes = cc
          .TB_CLIENTEs
          .Where(c => c.TEL_CLIENTE == numero)
          .ToList();
}
```

Se passar ele retorna `true` e executa tudo que está dentro do `if` e a comparação com decimal deve ser feita com igualdade.

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Método Decimal.TryParse (String, Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [decimal (Referência de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)
- [Estrutura Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx)